# Determine cardinlity of sets in GAMS

Tags: modeling

How can I determine the cardinality of a set in GAMS? Is there a keyword for this in GAMS?

Suppose I have the following declaration:

SET y  /1 * 10/ ;

I would like later in the model to make the asignment 
x = cardinality_of_y; 
How can I write this in GAMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator card() does the job.